# passing IndexPath to subview

Tags: iphone, ios, nsindexpath

Hi I am trying to pass an indexvalue from my parent view to my subview like this
//main.m

```
SubViewController *subViewController = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
subViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;
```

However when I try to check to see if the value have been passed over to the subview like so

//sub.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//
NSLog(@"%@", parentViewSelectedIndexPath);
//
```

decliration in side
sub.h

```
//
@interface VehicleResultViewController : UITableViewController {
//
NSIndexPath *parentViewSelectedIndexPath;
//
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *parentViewSelectedIndexPath;
//
@end
```

> //Answer
>
> subview loads before it gets the indexpath being passed to is.. so I
>   had to use a method that is executed later
>   i.s.(didselectrowatindexpath) this printed out the correct indexpath
>   that was sent to it from the main view.

it prints (null) to the console.. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's not enough code here to tell. For example, if you declared an ivar `parentViewSelectedIndexPath`, but then synthesized your property as `@synthesize parentViewSelectedIndexPath=_parentViewSelectedIndexPath`, then it would make perfect sense that accessing the ivar in `-viewDidLoad` isn't giving you the value of the property.

Comment: Sanity check: add `NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);` after you set `parentViewSelectedIndexPath`. What happens?

Comment: Additionally, if your -init method accesses `self.view` (which I hope it doesn't) then `-viewDidLoad` would fire before you've had a chance to set the property.

Comment: Show us the declaration code for parentViewSelectedIndexPath.

Comment: I have tried it in several methods and am still getting the (null) output.

Comment: updated with implemntation code.

Comment: That NSLog statement won't actually work.  You've used the "%@" print format specifier which expects you to provide an NSString, but you are providing an NSIndexPath.  Try: NSLog(@"%@", [parentViewSelectedIndexPath description]);

Comment: Also not sure if this is a typo, but your "sub.h" above is missing a close brace "}".  It should be present on the line immediately preceding the property declaration (@property).

Comment: damn.. thought that was going to work but still coming back as null..

Comment: I just tried NSLog where I set the IndexPath and it shows up after the NSLog in the subview.. so I need to try and NSlog else where in the subview as it seems to be loading before its pass the indexpath..

Comment: okay.. so as it turns out, the view loads before it gets the value being set to it.. so declaring inside viewdidload was incorrect.. I decided to test both versions of the NSLog discussed inside didselectrowatindexpath of the subview (so the part of the code where you go back to your main view) and both nslogs displayed the correct information.. thanks for the help guys.. will post example above.

Comment: @C.Johns you just helped me SOOO much thank you!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some `NSLog`s to determine the order of calls, @Kevin makes the point that `viewDidLoad` may be called prior to setting the property.

Also if the `indexPath` is always set whenever `subViewController` is instantiated it is good practice to create your own designated initializer with `indexPath` as a parameter.  In the case that @Kevin makes this is the answer.